# Gurobi Python: Unsupported type (<class 'tuple'>) for LinExpr addition argument Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gurobi

[image: Capacity Constraint]

I am trying to write the constraint as shown in the image. But getting the below error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- GurobiError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-112-d0e0b7b1cb5e> in <module>()
> ----> 1 Boiler_capacity = m.addConstrs((boiler_produced_thermal[t] <= boiler_thermal_max for t in time_slots), name = "Boiler_capacity")
> 
> model.pxi in gurobipy.Model.addConstrs
> (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:89458)()
> 
> model.pxi in gurobipy.Model.addConstr
> (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:87963)()
> 
> linexpr.pxi in gurobipy.LinExpr.__sub__
> (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:34728)()
> 
> linexpr.pxi in gurobipy.LinExpr.__add__
> (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:34333)()
> 
> linexpr.pxi in gurobipy.LinExpr.add
> (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:31162)()
> 
> GurobiError: Unsupported type (<class 'tuple'>) for LinExpr addition
> argument
```

What i have tried so far:

```
Boiler_capacity = m.addConstrs((boiler_produced_thermal[t] <= boiler_thermal_max for t in time_slots), name = "Boiler_capacity")
```

Where :

**boiler_produced_thermal** is variable with index time slot

**boiler_thermal_max** = 21000 is assigned to integer value.

**time_slots** = ['k1', 'k2','k3', 'k4', 'k5']

This code works:

Instead of using the *variable name*, if used the value assigned to a variable. It works. But i didn't get what is the actual reason behind this.

```
 Boiler_capacity = m.addConstrs((boiler_produced_thermal[t] <= 21000 for t in time_slots), name = "Boiler_capacity")
```

Can somebody help me to understand the problem?.

Comment: have you tried `Boiler_capacity = m.addConstrs(boiler_produced_thermal[t] <= 21000 for t in time_slots, name = "Boiler_capacity")` (note, no braces)
?`

Comment: @ingvar, yes i have tried without braces. It says generator expected `braces`.